# Silent Letters In Words Containing Double Letters

Tags: pronunciation, doubled-consonants, silent-letters

I'm doing an exercise, which says find the silent letters in some words. one of them is **"OFFICE"**

1. Does this word have 1 or 2 silent letters? **The final 'E'**     Or     **final 'E' + one of 'F's**
2. Are double letters considered one sound? if yes, Do they have any roles? for example putting stress there!

---

Consider the word 'aim'. Is that "i" considered silent letter? what about "steak". is that "a" useless and let's say that 'e' is making the 'eɪ' sound? these are many words like this. veil, may, rain, awful(NAmer)

Comment: +1 Interesting question. I don't think double letters qualify as silent letters unless both are silent because (1) it could be argued that both make a sound, they're just 'joined together'; and (2) I don't see a good reason for calling one silent and the other not. Another issue you might want to consider is whether letters that modify the sounds of others are truly silent - e.g. *us* vs *use*.

Comment: As your questions indicate, the term "silent letter" is impossible to define precisely. You should just ask whoever assigned the exercise to give a clear description of whatever definition you're meant to use.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_letter#English contains a detailed list of different types of silent letters.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which f do you think is silent?

Comment: @Airymouse Obviously the middle "f"!

Comment: In "sh", which letter makes the /ʃ/ sound? Both letters or just one and the other is silent? What about "x"? Which part makes the /k/ sound and which part makes the /s/ sound? Then there's "ch". Its sound is /tʃ/. Does the "c" make the /t/ sound and the "h" make the /ʃ/ sound?